# i have errors in my flutter code while getting data from ASP.net api which is hosted locally

Tags: flutter, api, flutter-test

I have errors in my flutter code while getting data from ASP.net API which is localhost. I am getting results in swagger and chrome but not getting a response in a flutter when I will call

following is the URL to call

```
     https://localhost:44363/address-lookup?address=house%20no%20122%20
    

    E/flutter ( 5191): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: SocketException: Connection refused (OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 111), address = localhost, port = 36591
    E/flutter ( 5191): #0      _NativeSocket.startConnect (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:682:35)
    E/flutter ( 5191): #1      _RawSocket.startConnect (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:1817:26)
    E/flutter ( 5191): #2      RawSocket.startConnect (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:27:23)
    E/flutter ( 5191): #3      RawSecureSocket.startConnect (dart:io/secure_socket.dart:299:22)
    E/flutter ( 5191): #4      SecureSocket.startConnect (dart:io/secure_socket.dart:77:28)
    E/flutter ( 5191): #5      _ConnectionTarget.connect (dart:_http/http_impl.dart:2449:26)
    E/flutter ( 5191): #6      _HttpClient._getConnection.connect (dart:_http/http_impl.dart:2867:12)
    E/flutter ( 5191): #7      _HttpClient._getConnection (dart:_http/http_impl.dart:2872:12)
    E/flutter ( 5191): #8      _HttpClient._openUrl (dart:_http/http_impl.dart:2727:12)
    E/flutter ( 5191): #9      _HttpClient.openUrl (dart:_http/http_impl.dart:2591:7)
    E/flutter ( 5191): #10     IOClient.send (package:http/src/io_client.dart:35:38)
    E/flutter ( 5191): #11     BaseClient._sendUnstreamed (package:http/src/base_client.dart:93:38)
    E/flutter ( 5191): #12     BaseClient.get (package:http/src/base_client.dart:27:7)
    E/flutter ( 5191): #13     get.<anonymous closure> (package:http/http.dart:46:36)
    E/flutter ( 5191): #14     _withClient (package:http/http.dart:164:20)
    E/flutter ( 5191): #15     get (package:http/http.dart:46:5)
    E/flutter ( 5191): #16     APIServices.fectchCordinates (package:callling_api_learning_localhost/Model/API_Services.dart:12:39)
    E/flutter ( 5191): #17     _MyAppState.initState (package:callling_api_learning_localhost/main.dart:17:17)
    E/flutter ( 5191): #18     StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4942:57)
    E/flutter ( 5191): #19     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4781:5)
    E/flutter ( 5191): #20     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3817:16)
    E/flutter ( 5191): #21     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3551:18)
    E/flutter ( 5191): #22     RenderObjectToWidgetElement._rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:1202:16)
    E/flutter ( 5191): #23     RenderObjectToWidgetElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:1171:5)
    E/flutter ( 5191): #24     RenderObjectToWidgetAdapter.attachToRenderTree.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:1119:18)
    E/flutter ( 5191): #25     BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2597:19)
    E/flutter ( 5191): #26     RenderObjectToWidgetAdapter.attachToRenderTree (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:1118:13)
    E/flutter ( 5191): #27     WidgetsBinding.attachRootWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:953:7)
    E/flutter ( 5191): #28     WidgetsBinding.scheduleAttachRootWidget.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:933:7)
    E/flutter ( 5191): #29     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1418:47)
    E/flutter ( 5191): #30     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1328:19)
    E/flutter ( 5191): #31     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1236:7)
    E/flutter ( 5191): #32     _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1276:23)
    E/flutter ( 5191): #33     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1426:13)
    E/flutter ( 5191): #34     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1328:19)
    E/flutter ( 5191): #35     _CustomZone.bindCallback.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1260:23)
    E/flutter ( 5191): #36     Timer._createTimer.<anonymous closure> (dart:async-patch/timer_patch.dart:18:15)
    E/flutter ( 5191): #37     _Timer._runTimers (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:398:19)
    E/flutter ( 5191): #38     _Timer._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:429:5)
    E/flutter ( 5191): #39     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:192:12)
    E/flutter ( 5191): 



[here is api response picture in browser][2]


  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WN8Jw.png
```

Comment: `Connection refused [...] address = localhost, port = 36591` in chrome `https://localhost:44363`, change your flutter to point to the correct port. Also, as a note, for future questions avoid spamming multiple language tags, it will only attract negative attention

Comment: As another note for future questions, avoid posting code as an image, code is text and should be included as properly formatted markdown text inside your question body

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are not able to connect to the local api is because `localhost`  points to `127.0.0.1` loppback address. I would suggest to open the port `44363` on firewall of the device hosting the API.

Then, instead of calling `https://localhost:44363/address-lookup?address=house%20no%20122%20`, call the url `https://server-ip:44363/address-lookup?address=house%20no%20122%20`.

The server-ip is the local network IP of the device hosting the network.

Swagger and chrome would receive the result because the server-ip is the same device. So, it works. But, running the app, you are on different network IPs. So, open the firewall port and connect using `http://server-IP:PORT`. It will work.

The error is firewall error. Unable to locate the server.